# Laravel 5 custom validation rule for existing tags

Tags: php, validation, laravel, customization, laravel-5

I'm searching for a cleaner way to validate tags when storing a Post.

All of the input validation takes place within my custom request `StorePostRequest`. The problem is that I need to check whether the given tags exist in the database, only existing tags are allowed. The function `$request->input('tags')` returns a string with comma seperated values, for example: `Tag1,Tag2,Tag3`.

Here is the code:

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  StorePostRequest $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function store(StorePostRequest $request)
{
    //THIS PIECE OF CODE
    $tags = explode(',', $request->input('tags'));
    $tags = Tag::whereIn('title', $tags)->lists('id');

    if(count($tags) < 1)
    {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors([ trans('tags.min') ]);
    }
    else if(count($tags) > 5)
    {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors([ trans('tags.max') ]);
    }
    //TILL HERE

    $post = $request->user()->posts()->create([
        'slug'          => unique_slug('Post', $request->input('title')),
        'title'         => $request->input('title'),
        'description'   => $request->input('description'),
        'summary'       => $request->input('summary'),
    ]);

    $post->tags()->attach($tags);

    return redirect(route('theme.post.show', [$theme->slug, $post->slug]))->with(['success', trans('messages.post.store')]);
}
```

The code is a little sloppy and redundant when using it in multiple controllers.

In order to solve this, I've created a `ValidationServiceProvider` to extend the core validator rules. Something like this:

```
$this->app['validator']->extend('tags', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    $tags = explode(',', $value);
    $tags = Tag::whereIn('title', $tags)->lists('id');

    if(count($tags) < 1 || count($tags) > 5))
    {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Pretty neat. The thing is I still need to be able to access the `$tags` variable within the controller (because of `->attach($tags)`).

Is there a better way of tackling this problem? Or should I stop thinking and just use (and repeat) the code I have?

Thanks in advance, hope it makes some sence.

Comment: You can create a ```TagsTransformer``` class that handles the transformation from a string to an array and use this on both the controller and the validator.

Comment: Yes that Is pretty nice. I now have a private function within my controller named `processTags()` which does the transformation and validation of the tags. It is alot better already.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you understand the use of this class because I have seen that you have defined `StorePostRequest` class. So, just for clarify, the `rules` method could looks like:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'tags' => ['required', 'tags'] //kb
    ];
}
```

Finally, with all the tools in correct place, you only make manipulate the data in your controllers like this:

```
public function store(StorePostRequest $request)
{
    // at this point, the tags are already validated, so we, proceed get them:
    $tags = explode(',', $$request->get('tags'));

    $post = $request->user()->posts()->create([
        'slug'          => unique_slug('Post', $request->input('title')),
        'title'         => $request->input('title'),
        'description'   => $request->input('description'),
        'summary'       => $request->input('summary'),
    ]);

    $post->tags()->attach($tags);

    return redirect(route('theme.post.show', [$theme->slug, $post->slug]))->with(['success', trans('messages.post.store')]);
}
```

> Keep in mind that inyecting `StorePostRequeststore` in the controller's function it is already validating and running the rules.

That is enough if you really has defined the StorePostRequest's rules correctly.

Comment: Yes I do, the rules are working fine. Problem is I need to explode the tags string, check if they exist in the database, return a list (array of id's) and then count. So I can't just use rules like `tags => 'required|array|min:1|max:5'.`. Also, `$request->input('tags')` returns a comma seperated string, so I can't use attach() on that in my controller.    Excuse me if I'm getting this wrong :)

Comment: I think you are so complicated. `tags` rule already has validated the count an existence. Why not just put `$tags = explode(',', $tags);` berfore `->attach($tags); ` call? Look edited answer

Comment: `$request->input('tags')` returns a string like `Tag1, Tag2, Tag3`. I must first find the tags in the database with that title, get their id's in a list and only then I can use `->attach($tag_ids)`

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($request->tags as $k=>$tags){
            $this->validate($request, [
                'tags.'.$k => 'required|string|max:20'
            ]);
        }
```